# Radiobutton checked by Prop, while not working with attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am selecting radio button using jquery based on textbox length. when I first select radiobutton using prop, all working fine. but when I work with attr, strange thing happens with following scenario.

Scenario: When all radio button first unchecked, and I select radiobutton using jquery, it works

but If I select another radio button and try to select previous radio button, it remains unselected

Here is link for Prop (which working all fine):

```
jsfiddle.net/Lo3qn6q8/
```

Here is link for attr (which is not working):

```
jsfiddle.net/hpmhxkdx/
```

If you say prop is better than attr, then when we use attr not prop?

Comment: jQuery < 1.6 uses `attr`

Comment: but when I select radiobutton with attr, it works not second time, why?

Comment: Because `attribute` of previously checked element is still there..

Comment: that's mean we should never use attr, right?

Comment: I would not say **NEVER** but one needs to understand the [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsbin.com/xopobuhubi/edit?html,console,output

The problem is that "checked" is a property, not an attribute. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp

You have to set it with .prop() (or as a property lookup on Native HTMLElement).

Comment: Yes,you must use prop instead of attr to set checked or you'll have a trouble when reset.